# Web form scaffold and not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frameworks, scaffolding

Is scaffolding possible with web forms code?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) is a scaffolding solution that should work with web forms and MVC.

Comment: MVC support is included with the Futures release.  http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20Data.  The question only mentions web forms, so he should be OK with the base DD support.