# Automatically create data entry form based on a database table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

Is there some add-in, control or something else for Visual Studio 2008 using which one can automatically generate a webform mapped to fields of SQL Server database table. For instance, based on a user details table, a webform should be automatically generated having labels and textboxes and submit button to enter data into that table.

I tried searching the internet and mostly I found solutions for CRUD, which I don't want.

So please help.

Cheers.

Comment: I think [Lightswitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch/overview) will do that. Why don't you want a CRUD solution? Isn't that what you are asking for?

Comment: I think you're looking for a `scaffolding` solution. Have you searched for that term? You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060885/web-form-scaffold-and-not-mvc/5061034#5061034) interesting.

Comment: hey guys thanks for quick replies, i'll look into them and will let you fellas know.I don't want a CRUD solution as i just want to accept data from users on a web form.